# rc.d start does not terminate?

Tags: bash, daemon, archlinux

So I wrote the Arch Linux rc.d script for `mongod` daemon (following [an example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Writing_rc.d_scripts)), but when I do:

```
sudo rc.d start mongod
```

it just gets stuck on:

```
:: Starting /usr/bin/mongod          [BUSY]
```

and never transitions to "DONE" phase. Any tips?

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# import predefined functions
. /etc/rc.conf
. /etc/rc.d/functions

# Point to the binary
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod

# Get the ARGS from the conf
. /etc/conf.d/crond

# Function to get the process id
PID=$(get_pid $DAEMON)

case "$1" in
   start)
    stat_busy "Starting $DAEMON"
    # Check the PID exists - and if it does (returns 0) - do no run
    [ -z "$PID" ] && $DAEMON $ARGS &> /dev/null
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        add_daemon $DAEMON
        stat_done
    else
        stat_fail
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
   stop)
        stat_busy "Stopping $DAEMON"
    kill -HUP $PID &>/dev/null

    rm_daemon $DAEMON
    stat_done
    ;;
   restart)
        $0 stop
    sleep 1
    $0 start
    ;;
    *)
        echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
esac
```

I've looked at how apache does it, but I can't figure out what they are doing that's different. Here's a piece of their `httpd` script:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    stat_busy "Starting Apache Web Server"
    [ ! -d /var/run/httpd ] && install -d /var/run/httpd
    if $APACHECTL start >/dev/null ; then
      add_daemon $daemon_name
      stat_done
    else
      stat_fail
      exit 1
    fi
    ;;
```

Comment: Does this line: `[ -z "$PID" ] && $DAEMON $ARGS &> /dev/null` ever actually return (i.e. does `mongod` properly background itself) or do you need to add a `&` to the end of that line? You can add `-x` to the `#!/bin/bash` line to trace the script progress and see where it's getting stopped...

Comment: Sadly no, it does not ever return... I'll try adding `&`

Comment: Added `&` worked, but it still spews out occasional output to the terminal (closing terminal window works ok for that though). Cheers!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using the [default mongodb init script](https://gist.github.com/3260682)  that is installed by pacman? Did you compile MongoDB yourself?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you are passing an $ARGS variable that is never actually defined. You will probably want to either pass some [configuration options](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters), or the location of a [mongodb.conf file](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration) using the -f or --config option, to inform the daemon of the location of your database, log file, IP bindings, etc.

The mongod defaults assume that you database location is /data/db/. If this does not exist, or the daemon does not have permissions to that location, then the init script will fail.

You should probably also run the daemon with a user account other than yourself or root (the default pacman package creates a user named mongodb), and give this user read/write access to the data path and log file.

```
[ -z "$PID" ] && /bin/su mongodb -c "/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --fork" > /dev/null
```

I would suggest referring to the [mongodb init script](https://gist.github.com/3260682) provided in the [Arch Community package](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/mongodb/), and comparing that to what you have here. Or, install MongoDB using pacman, which sets all of this up for you.

If all else fails, add some 'echo' commands inside of your *if* and *else* blocks to track down exactly where the init script is hanging, check mongodb's logs, and report back to us.

Comment: Didn't see that arch package. Or maybe it didn't work. In any case, I'll give a go and report back to you. But script looks great, thanks!

Comment: @drozzy For future reference, you can search the Arch repositories using `pacman -Ss [keyword]`. This will also tell you if you have installed a package already. You shouldn't have to compile/install MongoDB manually on Arch unless you have a specific need for it; and the package is always kept up to date.